# SQL DEVELOPER // Compilador-Log -> Error(3,3): PLS-00103

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de dar de alta un procedimiento. Necesitaría ayuda con el pragma excpetion_init. como sería en un caso así:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE Cliente_alta(id_cli CLIENTE.CUSTOMER_ID, nombre CLIENTE.NAME, id_vendedor CLIENTE.SALESPERSON_ID, limite_credito CLIENTE.CREDIT_LIMIT)
IS
  EXCEPTION null_credit_limit;
  EXCEPTION null_name;

BEGIN
  IF limite_credito is null THEN
    raise null_credit_limit;
  END IF;
  IF nombre is null THEN
    raise null_name;
  END IF;
  
  IF CHECK_EXISTENCIA_CLIENTE(upper(nombre)) = TRUE THEN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, SALESPERSON_ID, CREDIT_LIMIT)
    VALUES(id_cli, upper(nombre), id_vendedor, limite_credito);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cliente dado de alta correctamente!');
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error.');
  END IF;
  
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN null_credit_limit THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error.\nIngrese el limite de credito del cliente!');
    WHEN null_name THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error.\nIngrese el nombre del cliente!');
    WHEN name_in_table THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error.\nEl nombre del cliente ya existe!');
END;
```

La cuestión es la siguiente, el log me tira el siguiente error:

Error(3,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior external language

Comment: Estan mal declaradas las excepciones; las declaraciones son  identificador y tipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que has mezclado nomenclaturas de diferentes lenguajes.

Cuando haces

```sql
   create or replace PROCEDURE Cliente_alta(id_cli CLIENTE.CUSTOMER_ID, nombre CLIENTE.NAME, id_vendedor CLIENTE.SALESPERSON_ID, limite_credito CLIENTE.CREDIT_LIMIT)
IS
  EXCEPTION null_credit_limit;
  EXCEPTION null_name;
```

Estás intentando generar un tipo excepción propio. Algo así se declararía en lenguajes como Java, pero en PLSQL el tipo se pone DETRÁS del nombre.
Prueba lo siguiente:

```sql
   create or replace PROCEDURE Cliente_alta(id_cli CLIENTE.CUSTOMER_ID, nombre CLIENTE.NAME, id_vendedor CLIENTE.SALESPERSON_ID, limite_credito CLIENTE.CREDIT_LIMIT)
IS
  null_credit_limit EXCEPTION ;
  null_name EXCEPTION ;
```